# Moved file to typoed-folder

Tags: filesystem, mv

I moved

```
mv  ~/...path.../myFile.py ~/a/b/c/typoedFolder
```

I understand now that I should always have a trailing `/` to prevent these issues, but given that it happened - is there any hope of recovering `myFile.py`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure just reverse it:

```
mv ~/a/b/c/typoedFolder ~/a/b/c/myFile.py
```

The files has only changed its name. So you're fine in this case to simply rename it back.